# In the episode "Hide," why does the TARDIS mimic Clara?

Tags: plot-explanation, doctor-who

Presumably, soon after the events of the "The Doctor's Wife," the TARDIS gained a holographic interface.  We've seen ("Let's Kill Hitler") that it can change its appearance.

Why does the TARDIS choose to mirror Clara when it speaks to her in "Hide"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The visual interface states "I am programmed to select the image of a person you esteem". Clara has also stated that she feels that the TARDIS doesn't like her. It might be that the TARDIS wants to annoy her by saying that, of all people in the world, Clara only holds herself in high esteem.

Comment: Thanks - I missed that.  Interesting that it chose the Doctor when talking to the Doctor in LKH!

Comment: @Liath: It makes some sense. IIRC, in LKH, the TARDIS needed to convey important information to the Doctor, and he needed to believe it. Therefore, the TARDIS mimicked someone who is equally-or-more-smart than the Doctor, in order to heighten the chance of him actually listening rather than cleverly trying to do it his way.